# Seta no select com div e jquery

Tags: css, css3

```js
$( document ) . ready( function () {

 $( 'div#bloqueioSelect' ) . click( function () {

  if ( $( 'div#bloqueioSelect ul' ) . is( ':visible' ) )
   $( 'div#bloqueioSelect ul' ) . css( 'display', 'none' );
  else
   $( 'div#bloqueioSelect ul' ) . css( 'display', 'block' );

 } );

 $( 'div#bloqueioSelect ul li' ) . click( function () {
  $('input[type=hidden]#bloqueio'). val( $(this) . val() );
  alert($('input[type=hidden]#bloqueio'). val());
 } );

   } );
```

```css
div.selecao {
 width: 100px; 
 border: 1px #CCCCCC solid; 
} 
div.selecao div {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
div.selecao div:after {
 width: 40px;
 height: 30px;
 background: url("seta.jpg") no-repeat right #ddd;
}
div.selecao div,
div.selecao ul {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
div.selecao ul {
 display: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
div.selecao  ul li img {
 float: left;
}  
div.selecao  ul li {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=hidden value=' . $busca->getBloqueio() . '  name=bloqueia id=bloqueia />

<div class=selecao id=bloqueiaSelect>
 <div>Bloqueia</div>
 <ul>
     <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Bloquear Produto" /></li><!--
  --><li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Desbloquear Produto"/></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<br />
<input type=hidden value=' . $busca->getBloqueio() . '  name=bloqueio id=bloqueio />

<div class=selecao id=bloqueioSelect>
 <div>Bloqueio</div>
 <ul>
     <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Bloquear Produto" /></li><!--
  --><li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Desbloquear Produto"/></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

O **objetivo** aqui é **adicionar** uma `seta.jpg` na `div` como `after` mas está **aparecendo** a **seta**.

Onde estou errando?

Após algumas mudanças orientadas pelo colega Lucas... cheguei em:

```
div.selecao div::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: url("seta.jpg");
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Mas a saída não ficou legal.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Bloqueia** precisa centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente e a seta precisa ir toda para a direita.

Comment: Já verificou se aparece algum erro no Console falando se a imagem não foi encontrada? Já verificou se é sete.jpg mesmo? Normalmente essas imagens são .PNG ou .GIF

Comment: hugo, sim já ví!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, boa noite

Para que o `:after`, assim como o `:before` funcione, você deve definir seu conteúdo.  Como no seu caso o conteúdo será uma imagem e não um elemento qualquer, como um texto, você não precisa preenchê-lo, entretanto deve defini-lo como vazio. Parece que isso está faltando em seu código. Mude o trecho do css para:

```
div.selecao div::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url("seta.jpg") no-repeat right #ddd;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Para rotacionar o elemento, utilize a função do CSS [`rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate). Veja:

```
#elemento{
    transform: rotate(360deg); // rotaciona 360 graus
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: não apareceu a imagem

Comment: adiconei infomações ao final da pergunta.

Comment: Por favor, tente de novo com as atualizações.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o porque da seta não aparecer o amigo Lucas já falou o motivo, vc não colocou o `content` no `::after`.

Sobre o alinhamento da seta vc pode colocar `position:relative` no botão e `position:absolite` no `::after` com `right:0` assim ele fica colado no canto direito. E para alinhar o texto descontando a largura da imagem que é `40px` basta usar um `margin` negativo com esse valor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Lógico que se o seu botão for pequeno de mais a imagem fica por cima do texto.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('div#bloqueioSelect').click(function () {

    if ($('div#bloqueioSelect ul').is(':visible'))
      $('div#bloqueioSelect ul').css('display', 'none');
    else
      $('div#bloqueioSelect ul').css('display', 'block');

  });

  $('div#bloqueioSelect ul li').click(function () {
    $('input[type=hidden]#bloqueio').val($(this).val());
    alert($('input[type=hidden]#bloqueio').val());
  });

});
```

```css
div.selecao {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao div {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

div.selecao div::after {
 content: "";
 width: 40px;
 height: 30px;
 background: url("https://placecage.com/40/30") no-repeat right #ddd;
 display: block;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

div.selecao div,
div.selecao ul {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #F8F8F8;
 border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao ul {
 display: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

div.selecao ul li img {
 float: left;
}

div.selecao ul li {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=hidden value=' . $busca->getBloqueio() . ' name=bloqueia id=bloqueia />

<div class=selecao id=bloqueiaSelect>
 <div>Bloqueia</div>
 <ul>
  <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Bloquear Produto" /></li>
  <!--
   -->
  <li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Desbloquear Produto" /></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<br />
<input type=hidden value=' . $busca->getBloqueio() . ' name=bloqueio id=bloqueio />

<div class=selecao id=bloqueioSelect style="width: 200px;">
 <div>
  <span style="margin-left: -40px;">Bloqueio</span>
 </div>
 <ul>
  <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Bloquear Produto" /></li>
  <!--
   -->
  <li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" style="height:30px" title="Desbloquear Produto" /></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```